# How to calculate the dual spaces of the following spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, probability-distributions

Let us consider the spaces $C_\infty(E)$, $C_c(E)$, $C_b(E)$, where $E$ is locally compact, $C_\infty(E）$ is all continuous functions vanishing at the ends of $E$, $C_c(E)$ is all the continuous functions with compact support and $C_b(E)$ is all the bounded continuous functions.
How do we find the dual spaces $C^*_\infty(E)$, $C^*_c(E)$, $C^*_b(E)$.

For $C_\infty^*$, I have a naïve idea but I am not sure it is correct. We know that functions in $C_\infty$ are almost to the normal distribution $\delta_{E_i}(x)$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$. In some sense this kind of function is the basics of $C_\infty$.  Using the Riesz representation we get the functional $l$ has the following representation $l(f(x))=\int f(x)\mu(dx)$. Plug in $\delta_{E_i}(x)$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$. We get the following $ l(f(x))=\sum_{i}^N \delta(x)\mu(E_i)$. Then $C_\infty^*=\overline{\{\sum_{i}^N \delta(x)\mu(E_i)\}}$, the linear span of sign measure. Is this correct?
If it is correct, how to get the another two dual space $ C^*_c(E)$, $C^*_b(E)$?
If it is not, can someone give me some idea or reference to calculate the dual spaces $C^*_\infty(E)$, $C^*_c(E)$, $C^*_b(E)$?

Comment: $C_c(E)$ is not Banach, and its completion under the $\sup$-norm is $C_{\infty}(E)$. (I'm supposing your $f(\infty)=0$ means $f$ vanishes at the ends of $E$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a concrete but disappointing answer to your question. Let me discard $C_c(E)$ as it is not a Banach space and let us focus on what you call $C_\infty$ but it is more commonly denoted by $C_0(E)$. In this case the dual space is the space of all Borel measures on $E$ with the total variation norm, see also [A question on the Riesz-Markov theorem about dual space of $C_0(X)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414481/a-question-on-the-riesz-markov-theorem-about-dual-space-of-c-0x).

The space $C_b(E)$ can be humongous. For instance, when $E = \mathbb N$ it is naturally identifiable with $\ell_\infty$, the space of all bounded sequences. More generally, you may identify that $C_b(E)$ is canonically isometrically isomorphic to $C(\beta E)$, where $\beta E$ stands for the [Čech–Stone compactification of $E$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification). So by the Riesz representation theorem, the dual of $C_b(E)$ is just the space of Borel measures on $\beta E$. You probably can't do better as already for $E=\mathbb N$ this dual space is a mess.